# Как создать каталог в OneDriveClient

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, onedrive

Как создать каталог с помощью `IOneDriveClient` (`OneDriveClientExtensions.GetUniversalClient(scopes)`)?
Поиск выдаёт только чтение и создание файлов и каталогов. Но не нашёл создания каталога. Без REST!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Move, copy, create, or delete a file or folder on OneDrive (REST)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn659743.aspx)

[Работа с папками и файлами Microsoft OneDrive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh826531.aspx)

Нашел то что вам нужно:

```
 var folderToCreate = new Item { Name = folderName, Folder = new Folder() };
    var newFolder = await client.Drive.Items[parentId].Children.Request().AddAsync(folderToCreate);
```

Источник, https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/issues/24

Comment: Нужно не это. Нужно через указанную библиотеку. REST уже на крайний случай.

Comment: @jonsbox Обновил ответ