# Visual Studio C# синхронизация файлов

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ftp, windows-10, uwp

Есть универсальный проект Windows 10 в среде Visual Studio на C#. Как можно осуществить синхронизацию файлов? Нужно при желании загружать или выгружать файлы. Ранее на Python е делал такую синхронизацию через FTP, но тут я нашел информацию только на сайте MSDN информацию про FTP для VS ... и то, только для скачивания. Про загрузку на ftp сервер ни слова. Может есть более полная информация на счет встроенных функций, или к примеру расширение NuGet с необходимыми библиотеками ... и инструкцией для использования =).

PS: еще читал про связку через облачный сервис Azure, но сервис вроде как платный да и при попытке попробовать не смог зарегистрироваться... нету банковской карточки на свое имя. Ну а ради этого идти и оформлять как то не обдумано.

Comment: _"при попытке попробовать"_ -- можно скачать Azure SDK. есть эмулятор некоторых сервисов. и explorer который встраивается в Visual Studio.

Comment: На сколько мне известно, бесплатно пользоваться сервисом Azure можно только в течении месяца. Такой вариант не подходит.

Answer (score 3):

> Как можно осуществить синхронизацию файлов? Нужно при желании загружать или выгружать файлы.

Файлы можно синхронизировать через OneDrive. Предоставляется бесплатно несколько гигабайт.
Есть OneDrive API. Почитайте - [тут](http://isdk.dev.live.com/dev/isdk/Default.aspx).
И есть nuget-пакет [LiveSDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LiveSDK/).

Для UWP есть [OneDrive API 2.0](https://dev.onedrive.com).

Comment: Интересная работа расширения. Единственное пример в указаннйо сылке на JS. Нашел руководство [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh243641.aspx#clientid) но сразу же столкнулся с проблемой. В руководстве ни слова о том, где загрузить расширение. Скачал по второй вашей ссылке, но похоже что LiveSDK из nuget не подошел. using Microsoft.Live; не находит, а в XAML тега <live:SignInButton> и в помине нету.

Comment: для uwp добавил в ответ.

Comment: возможно подойдет ответ [Как создать каталог в OneDriveClient](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/475863/)